# How to get data from retrofit when data is like this as given below

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

When I try to get name while parsing the response from the server, I am getting `null`. Can u please help me to get data i.e, name, email and keyskills.name?

The JSON response is here.

```
{
"freelancer": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "trinadh",
    "title": "web developer",
    "email": "trinadh_freelancer@gmail.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "dob": "2018-09-27",
    "website": "www.trinadh_freelancer.com",
    "country": "India",
    "state": "Karnataka",
    "city": "Bangalore",
    "user_id": 52,
    "user_role": "freelancer",
    "registered": null,
    "agreement": true,
    "address": "hsr layout",
    "qualification": "b.tech",
    "total_experience": "2",
    "prefered_location": "",
    "category": "Web Development",
    "pancard_number": "ajhfvbqjhe",
    "passport_number": "hbhfjdhbjfh",
    "country_code": null,
    "contact_number": "8765456721",
    "currency_type": "INR",
    "rate": "678.0",
    "rate_card_type": "per_hour",
    "negotiable": true,
    "taxes": "Taxes Excluded",
    "key_skills": {
        "name": "ruby",
        "relevant_experience": "2"
    },
    "other_skills": {
        "name": "animation",
        "relevant_experience": "3"
    },
    "confirmed_at": "24-Sep-2018",
    "free_trail_days_left": 83,
    "renewal_date": "24-Mar-2019",
    "image": "<img src=\"\" />"
}
}
```

Here is my pojo class

```
public class FreeLancer {
    private List<FreeLancerProfile> freelancer;

    // Constructors, getters and setters are removed for convenience
}
```

Here is my freelancer profile

```
public class FreeLancerProfile {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String title;
    private String email;
    private String gender;
    private String dob;
    private String website;
    private String country;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private int user_id;
    private String user_role;
    private String registered;
    private String agreement;
    private String address;
    private String qualification;
    private String total_experience;
    private String prefered_location;
    private String category;
    private String pancard_number;
    private String passport_number;
    private String country_code;
    private String contact_number;
    private String currency_type;
    private String rate;
    private String rate_card_type;
    private String negotiable;
    private String taxes;
    private List<KeySkill> key_skills;
    private List<OtherSkill> other_skills;
    private String confirmed_at;
    private String free_trail_days_left;
    private String renewal_date;
    private String image;

    // Constructors, getters and setters are removed for convenience
}
```

My Pojo class for key skills

```
public class KeySkill {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String relevant_experience;

    // Constructors, getters and setters are removed for convenience
}
```

My Interface

```
public interface FreeLancerMainApi {

    @GET("{fullUrl}/profile")
    Call<FreeLancerProfile> freeLancerMain(
            @Path(value = "fullUrl", encoded = true) String fullUrl,
            @Header("Authorization") String token
    );

    @GET("{fullUrl}/profile")
    Call<KeySkill> keySkillsMain(
            @Path(value = "fullUrl", encoded = true) String fullUrl,
            @Header("Authorization") String token
    );
}
```

My Main Avtivity

```
String BASE_URL = "http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/freelancers/";

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
final FreeLancerMainApi api = retrofit.create(FreeLancerMainApi.class);

Call<FreeLancerProfile> call = api.freeLancerMain(freelancer_id, token);

call.enqueue(new Callback<FreeLancerProfile>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<FreeLancerProfile> call, Response<FreeLancerProfile> response) {
        if (response.code() == 200)
        {
            name = response.body().getName();
            email = response.body().getEmail();
            contactNumber = response.body().getContact_number();
            Toast.makeText(FreelancerActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<FreeLancerProfile> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});

Call<KeySkill> call1 = api.keySkillsMain(freelancer_id, token);
call1.enqueue(new Callback<KeySkill>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<KeySkill> call, Response<KeySkill> response) {
        if (response.code() == 200){
            skills = response.body().getName();
        }else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<KeySkill> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});

freeLancerMainName.setText(name);
freeLancerMainEmail.setText(email);
freeLancerContactNumber.setText(contactNumber);
freeLancerKeySkills.setText(skills);
```

I am getting null response as when I execute this code. Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you confirm if your JSON is valid? At the end of response, you've 'renewal_date' with a comma at the end... is there another variable which you are not sharing?

Comment: ya at last i have another line "renewal_date": "24-Mar-2019",
        "image": "<img src=\"\" />"
    }
}

Comment: But you don't cover that variable in your class?

Comment: while coping i missed it sorry

Comment: i have modified it

Comment: What about your FreeLancerProfile  class?

Comment: i have changed it

Comment: Before I respond with something, the code in the question right now, is it the up to date code? If not, please update it and notify me.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the response, it is not returning an array or a list. However, as far as I have understood from your code, you are expecting to parse the response into a list.

The `Freelancer` pojo should look like the following.

```
public class FreeLancer {
    public FreeLancerProfile freelancer;
}
```

If everything else is okay, it should work fine.

**UPDATE:**

The response should be bound to `FreeLancer` class, not to `FreeLancerProfile` class. I have shown an example, which might help. Please check.

```
public void onResponse(Call<FreeLancer> call, Response<FreeLancer> response) {
    if (response.code() == 200) {
        FreeLancer freelancer = response.body();

        name = freelancer.getName();
        email = freelancer.getEmail();
        // Others ... 
    }
}
```

And in your `FreelancerProfile` pojo, you need to remove the `List` from the `key_skills` and `other_skills` as well. These are not lists as well.

```
private KeySkill key_skills;
private OtherSkill other_skills;
```

Comment: then how i can get name and email

Comment: then i am getting the error that methods should be same

Comment: My bad, please change your `FreelancerProfile` classes to `Freelancer` everywhere and check if that works now.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Can you please write down the error here?

Comment: response.body().getEmail() here i am getting getEmail() in red color ie can't resolve the method getEmail() even getName(),,,,,

Comment: Please remove the `body()` part as I mentioned in my code. Just use `response.getEmail()`.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you please check now?

Comment: You might also consider catching this [tutorial here](http://www.androiddeft.com/2017/10/08/retrofit-android/).

Comment: I think you need to check the tutorial on how to parse JSON data using Retrofit in Android. If you have already made the changes in your pojo classes that I suggested, you are fine. Just check if there is anything wrong with your JSON parsing. I have provided a tutorial in the comment above.

Comment: in recycler view i am getting output. but for single data i am not getting output i am getting null response